# UIButton on XIB visible in parent view but IBAction not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So I am trying to add a view as a subview onto an exisiting View Controller by loading it from an XIB in such manner -

```
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.view.frame = aView.frame;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [aView addSubview:self.view];
    if (animated) {
        [self showAnimation];
    }
});
}
```

I see the button on the parent View Controller and it gets pressed too with the little animation that is there on UIButtons by default. The problem is that the IBAction connected to the UIButton never gets called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it may the cause of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{} block

Comment: how did you connect that button to the IBAction?

Comment: Tried to define an IBAction and then connecting it to the UIButton, didn't work.. Also Ctrl+dragged from the UIButton onto the .m file.. Still nothing

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @oye make sure you have defined the child view as a class variable and not as a local variable. As far as I remember, this is what solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding the view as a class variable instead of a local variable did it for me.